# Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: h

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, react-native-cli

Every time I try to run the emulator using npx react-native run-android command it gives me this error Please help

[image: img]

Nearly tried all the solutions that were found on the internet but this did not help(clear cache, restart etc. every time I try to run my android emulator it gives this error. I have already updated my JDK and installed version 11 and Gradle updated through the android studio. unable to find the root cause for this error.
Note
My project is in React Native

My package.json

[image: My package.json]

Comment: If you check there is "keystore password was incorrect" in error. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i get to know that the error was for key store so I removed all the steps that was done to create build and finally it started normally